# Retrieving first value of css property after changing by jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that there is a `div` element and we are in `760px` width. Current `margin-top` as `css` property value will be `60px`.

### CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
    div.me {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
    div.me {
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
}
```

Then I change the `margin-top` by `jquery` to do more stuff. e.g. `80px`.

### Jquery

```
$("div.me").css("margin-top", "80px");
```

---

**I'm searching a solution for:** When the user resized the window, Doing reset the element `margin-top` to first `documnet ready` value depend on it's media query.

Suppose the user resized to `400px` width. So the element should be reset to `margin-top: 30px`.

I thought to set custom attributes to all elements to save first values in it.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var m = $("div.me").css("margin-top");
    $("div.me").attr("first-margin-top", m);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    // some stuff to retrieve first value, not important...
});
```

But There are many elements like this on the page and many media query values for each.. Here I just talked about one element.

Is there a better way to retrieve and reset the element? Any idea?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but does your CSS not already 'reset' the margin back to `30px`?

Comment: @putvande You mentioned good. But I don't know why after changing by jquery, It not return back to media query value in the resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer of my own question. I just changed inline style to `""` or removed it. It makes the browser to set `margin-top` or other properties (if needed) according to `media query` values again.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("div.me").css("margin-top", "");
    //or
    $("div.me").removeAttr("style");
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/rfNZy/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You set the CSS value inline therefore it trumps your media query.  Either do this with jquery or add the !important tag into your css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
    div.me {
        margin-top: 60px !important;
    }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    if($(window).width < 760){
      $("div.me").css("margin-top", "60px");
    }
});
```

Comment: `!important` is good idea but It did not allow `jquery` to change margin for `width>760`. Also in your case I have to set all css media query conditions again in jquery...

Comment: I would suggest the jquery if statement then.  If is is less than or equal to 760px then add the margin, else add the margin that is higher.